# InnerHtml se salta required

Tags: javascript

Cuando se añaden input type="text" debido a que has seleccionado un número de hermanos > 0 el InnerHtml me añade dichos input, pero me envía al hola.html y no debería porque los input son required.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Form</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function cargar(){

        document.getElementById("idbtnsend").addEventListener("click",repaso,false);

        function repaso(evento){
          var confi = confirmar();

          if(confi) {
            alert("final prven");
          }else{
            evento.preventDefault();
          }

        }

    }

    function hermanos(){

        var txt='';
        document.getElementById("nuevocontenido").innerHTML = txt;
        var hermanos =  document.getElementById("Idhermano").value;

        if(hermanos > 0){
            var contador = 0;

            while (contador != hermanos){
              contador++;
              txt += "<label for='hermano'>Hermano "  + contador + "Nombre: <input type='text' id='idtxtnombre"+contador+"' name='txtnombre"+contador+"' value='' required></label><br/>";
              txt += "<label for='hermano'>Hermano "  + contador + "Apellido: <input type='text' name='txtapellido"+contador+"' value=''  required></label><br/>";
            }

            document.getElementById("nuevocontenido").innerHTML += txt;
            document.getElementById("idtxtnombre1").focus();
        }

    }


    function confirmar(){

        var listasexo = document.formconf.elements["genero"];
        var sexo;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < listasexo.length; i++){
            if(listasexo[i].checked){
                sexo = listasexo[i].value;
            }
        }

        var hermanos =  document.getElementById("Idhermano").value;

        var dni = document.getElementById("Idtxtdni").value; 
        var nombre = document.getElementById("Idtxtname").value;
        var apellido = document.getElementById("Idtxtapellido").value;
        var direccion = document.getElementById("Idtxtdireccion").value;
        var edad = document.getElementById("Idtxtedad").value;
        var fecha = document.getElementById("Idtxtfecha").value;
        var mvl = document.getElementById("Idtxtmvl").value;

        var confi =  confirm("Enviando ??" + dni + "Con nombre: "+ nombre + " ,Apellidos: " +apellido + " ,con "+ hermanos + " ,Sexo: " + sexo +  " ,Dirección: " + direccion +  " ,edad: " +edad + " ,nacido: " + fecha +  " , teléfono: " + mvl);

        return confi;  

    }  

  </script>

</head>
<body onload="cargar();">
    <main>

        <form name="formconf" action="hola.html" method="POST">

            <label for="nombre">DNI: <input type="text" name="txtdni" id="Idtxtdni" value=""    required></label><br/>
            <label for="nombre">NOMBRE: <input type="text" name="txtname" id="Idtxtname" value="" required></label><br/>
            <label for="apellido">APELLIDO: <input type="text" name="txtapellido" id="Idtxtapellido" value="" required></label><br/>
            <label for="hermanos">Hermanos: <input type="number" name="txthermano" id="Idhermano" value="" onblur="hermanos();"></label><br/>
            <fieldset>
             <legend> Sexo </legend>
              <input type="radio" name="genero" value="Hombre"  > <label for="genhom">Hombre</label>
              <input type="radio" name="genero" value="Mujer"  > <label for="genmuj">Mujer</label>
            </fieldset>
            <label for="direccion">DIRECCIÓN: <input type="text" name="txtdireccion" id="Idtxtdireccion" value="" required></label><br/>
            <label for="edad">EDAD: <input type="number" name="txtedad" id="Idtxtedad" value=""  required></label><br/>
            <label for="fecha_nac">FECHA NAC: <input type="text" name="txtfecha" id="Idtxtfecha" value=""   required></label><br/>
            <label for="telefono">TELEFONO: <input type="text" name="txtmvl" id="Idtxtmvl" value=""  required></label><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="idbtnsend" name="btnsend" >
        </form>

     <div id="nuevocontenido">

     </div>

    </main>  
</body>
</html>
```

//------ hola.html

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Llegada Form</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  llegué

  </body>
</html>
```

Se puede ver muy rápido como el innerHtml añade bien los inputs pero rápidamente me manda al hola.html y debería quedarse en el FORM porque los nuevos input son de tipo de required y eso que le pongo el foco para que lo detecte el html...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás insertando nuevos Inputs **FUERA** del formulario, ya que el `div` #nuevoContenido está fuera de este.
La solución sería meter el `#nuevoContenido` dentro del `form` para que la norma de requiered sea aplicada.
El atrributo `required` solo funciona dentro de el elemento `form`

Añado un snippet con la solución:

```js
    function cargar(){

        document.getElementById("idbtnsend").addEventListener("click",repaso,false);

        function repaso(evento){
          var confi = confirmar();

          if(confi) {
            alert("final prven");
          }else{
            evento.preventDefault();
          }

        }

    }

    function hermanos(){

        var txt='';
        document.getElementById("nuevocontenido").innerHTML = txt;
        var hermanos =  document.getElementById("Idhermano").value;

        if(hermanos > 0){
            var contador = 0;

            while (contador != hermanos){
              contador++;
              txt += "<label for='hermano'>Hermano "  + contador + "Nombre: <input type='text' id='idtxtnombre"+contador+"' name='txtnombre"+contador+"' value='' required></label><br/>";
              txt += "<label for='hermano'>Hermano "  + contador + "Apellido: <input type='text' name='txtapellido"+contador+"' value=''  required></label><br/>";
            }

            document.getElementById("nuevocontenido").innerHTML += txt;
            document.getElementById("idtxtnombre1").focus();
        }

    }


    function confirmar(){

        var listasexo = document.formconf.elements["genero"];
        var sexo;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < listasexo.length; i++){
            if(listasexo[i].checked){
                sexo = listasexo[i].value;
            }
        }

        var hermanos =  document.getElementById("Idhermano").value;

        var dni = document.getElementById("Idtxtdni").value; 
        var nombre = document.getElementById("Idtxtname").value;
        var apellido = document.getElementById("Idtxtapellido").value;
        var direccion = document.getElementById("Idtxtdireccion").value;
        var edad = document.getElementById("Idtxtedad").value;
        var fecha = document.getElementById("Idtxtfecha").value;
        var mvl = document.getElementById("Idtxtmvl").value;

        var confi =  confirm("Enviando ??" + dni + "Con nombre: "+ nombre + " ,Apellidos: " +apellido + " ,con "+ hermanos + " ,Sexo: " + sexo +  " ,Dirección: " + direccion +  " ,edad: " +edad + " ,nacido: " + fecha +  " , teléfono: " + mvl);

        return confi;  

    }
```

```html
<body onload="cargar();">
    <main>

        <form name="formconf" action="hola.html" method="POST">

            <label for="nombre">DNI: <input type="text" name="txtdni" id="Idtxtdni" value=""    required></label><br/>
            <label for="nombre">NOMBRE: <input type="text" name="txtname" id="Idtxtname" value="" required></label><br/>
            <label for="apellido">APELLIDO: <input type="text" name="txtapellido" id="Idtxtapellido" value="" required></label><br/>
            <label for="hermanos">Hermanos: <input type="number" name="txthermano" id="Idhermano" value="" onblur="hermanos();"></label><br/>
            <fieldset>
             <legend> Sexo </legend>
              <input type="radio" name="genero" value="Hombre"  > <label for="genhom">Hombre</label>
              <input type="radio" name="genero" value="Mujer"  > <label for="genmuj">Mujer</label>
            </fieldset>
            <label for="direccion">DIRECCIÓN: <input type="text" name="txtdireccion" id="Idtxtdireccion" value="" required></label><br/>
            <label for="edad">EDAD: <input type="number" name="txtedad" id="Idtxtedad" value=""  required></label><br/>
            <label for="fecha_nac">FECHA NAC: <input type="text" name="txtfecha" id="Idtxtfecha" value=""   required></label><br/>
            <label for="telefono">TELEFONO: <input type="text" name="txtmvl" id="Idtxtmvl" value=""  required></label><br/>
     <div id="nuevocontenido">

     </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="idbtnsend" name="btnsend" >
        </form>



    </main>  
</body>
```

PD: Realmente yo utilizaría [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) para manejar el enevento `onChange` en el input de hermanos y [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) para el estilo del form